# Node takes too long to run and use too much ram

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, npm-start

I'm building a website with react. whenever I start react app using `npm start`. it takes too much time to exicute **(almost 30-40 minutes)**. and after starting the app my laptop be too much slower. How can I fix this problem.?

> Note: I have used `yarn start` and almost same result.

Comment: Check in the task manager . the cpu or the ram may be on full compacity

Comment: Are you just using plain js with jsx or are you using React with Typescript?

Comment: I am using javascript

Comment: @yanirmidler node taking more than 1gb of ram